# Why doesn't typescript check an option argument?

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't typescript show any type errors for the following example?

```
function fancyMethod({ option1 = true }: { option1?: boolean } = {}) {
    console.log(option1);
}

fancyMethod("abc");
fancyMethod(false);
fancyMethod(42);
```

[Try it yourself using this Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20fancyMethod(%7B%20option1%20%3D%20true%20%7D%3A%20%7B%20option1%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(option1)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AfancyMethod(%22abc%22)%3B%0AfancyMethod(false)%3B%0AfancyMethod(42)%3B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force TypeScript to accept only objects by merging your type with `object` type:

```
function fancyMethod({ option1 = true }: { option1?: boolean } & object = {}) {
    console.log(option1);
}

fancyMethod("abc");
fancyMethod(false);
fancyMethod(42);
fancyMethod({}); // no error
```

Comment: Maybe even better: `type NonPrimitive<T> = object & T;`

`function fancyMethod({ option1 = true }: NonPrimitive<{ option1?: boolean }> = {}) `

Answer (score 3):

So the type of the argument to `fancyMethod` is that is must be an object with optionally a boolean property `option1`.

All of the parameters you passed in are objects that don't have an `option1` property but that's alright as it is optional, so in each case you'll just get the default `option1 = true`.

A shorter example that shows the same thing:

```
let x: { option1?: boolean } = "abc";
x = 42;
```

Both the string and the number are compatible with a type where all of the properties are optional.

However, if you now try:

```
x = { foo: 1 };
```

you get an error:

```
t.ts(11,7): error TS2322: Type '{ foo: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ option1?: boolean | undefined; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type '{ option1?: boolean | undefined; }'.
```

because there is additional checking if you pass in an object literal with properties that are not part of the type, and the same happens if you try to pass an object literal with additional properties to `fancyMethod()`

Comment: So the only way would be:

`fancyMethod({ option1 = true }: { option1: boolean } = { option1 : true }) { .. }`

Comment: @jantimon There is way to workaround it: `fancyMethod({ option1 = true }: { option1?: boolean } & object = {}) { .. }`

Comment: Looks like they are about to fix it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16047

Comment: thanks @AnyName I'll go with that - can you add it as an answer?